# Unable to connect to ms database with PHP

Tags: php, database, ms-access

I have the following code trying to connect to the MS access database with PHP

```
            <?php
              $dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\punawai\\checkin.mdb";
              if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
              die("Could not find database file.");
              }

              $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; 
              Uid=; Pwd=;");

               ?>
```

But its gives me the following output:

![Output:][1]

NOTE: PHP, MS-ACCESS are both 64 bits

Below are the configuration I followed online about the PHP.ini and the MS ODBC

![PDO][2]
![OBDC][3]
![OBDC][4]

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg5FZ.png

![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS3oq.png

![3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzhFL.png

![4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w26TA.png

Comment: This: `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\punawai\\checkin.mdb"` is obviously invalid. You provide an absolute path (starting from the C drive) and then prepend the document root, which leads to an invalid path. Just do `$dbName = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\punawai\\checkin.mdb";`. Or use an actual relative path.

Comment: Thx for the help, what would I put down for an relative path?

Comment: That depends on where the file is kept with respect to document root. Use `echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];`, then scrap that part of the link. But note that solutions involving Access do require the code to run in a Windows machine with Access installed, so are often not very portable.